# Starter react example showing a blank page

Tags: reactjs

I recently started learning Reactjs. I have written this simple piece of code which is just showing a blank page. There are no errors, but all I see is a blank page... Can anyone please advise what I am doing wrong ? My IDE is Visual Studio.

Here is my code ...

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.2/react.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="results"></div>
    <script type="text/jsx">
        var hello = React.createClass({
        render : function(){
        return
        <h1>this.props.text</h1>;
        }
        });
        React.render(
        <div>
            <hello text="Hello Rotls">is hekii 1</hello>
            <hello text="Hello Rotls">is hekii 2</hello>
            <hello text="Hello Rotls">is hekii 3</hello>
        </div>
        ,document.getElementById('results'));
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to link JSX transformer script to parse your jsx content on the fly. Without it browser will not understand what inside `<script type="text/jsx">` and will just ignore that.

In order your example to work, you should add this script after ReactJS script

```
<script src="https://fb.me/JSXTransformer-0.13.3.js"></script>
```

Check jsbin https://jsbin.com/sicivomigo/edit?html,console,output

While it is ok for test projects, in production you should compile jsx into js to avoid runtime compiling jsx and speed up your app.

Now React has deprecated using runtime JSX transform and suggest using Webpack or Browserify with react extensions for compiling jsx into js alongside with bundling and minifying.

Here the good article about how to setup React with Webpack and Babel https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/08/setting-up-react-for-es6-with-webpack-and-babel-2.html

Comment: `You are using the in-browser JSX transformer. Be sure to precompile your JSX for production`